# Проблема положения курсора в React приложении

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**Всем привет.**
Я новичок в веб деве. Никак не могу найти информацию по моему вопросу.
Смысл моей задачи такой - при нажатии клавиши "ArrowUp" первая часть в input, где отображается день должна выделяться и увеличиваться на единицу **23/10/2021 => 24/10/2021**, при этом остальная часть должна оставаться неизменной, а при нажатии "ArrowDown" наоборот. Проблемы две. Первая заключается в том, что при нажатии число выделяется и прибавляется, но при последующем нажатии курсор передвигается в начало и выделение пропадает. Как сохранить состояние выделения и предотвратить перемещение курсора? Вторая проблема при нажатии например клавиши "ArrowUp"(прибавить число),а затем "ArrowDown" уменьшить число => число два раза увеличивается, третье нажатие начинает уменьшать число. То есть выходит, что при нажатии уменьшить число он срабатывает со второго раза.
Надеюсь я справился с объяснением.))

**PS**: если убрать inputEl.current.selectionStart === 1, то состояние выделения сохраняется, но мне нужно отлавливать положение курсора для изменения остальных частей инпута.

**Мой код**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import styles from "./DataInput.module.css";

const cur_date = new Date();

const def_day = cur_date.getDate();
const def_month = cur_date.getMonth();
const def_year = cur_date.getFullYear();
const def_hour = cur_date.getHours();
const def_minute = cur_date.getMinutes();
const def_seconds = cur_date.getSeconds();

/* const months = {
  1: "January",
  2: "February",
  3: "March",
  4: "April",
  5: "May",
  6: "June",
  7: "July",
  8: "August",
  9: "September",
  10: "October",
  11: "November",
  12: "December",
}; */

const DataInput = () => {
  const [milisec, setMilisec] = useState(cur_date.valueOf());
  const [date, setDate] = useState({
    day: def_day,
    month: def_month,
    year: def_year,
    hour: def_hour,
    minute: def_minute,
    second: def_seconds,
  });

  const { day, month, year, hour, minute, second } = date;
  const date_format = `${("0" + day).slice(
    -2
  )}/${month}/${year} ${hour}:${minute}:${second}`;

  const inputEl = useRef();
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selection) return; // prevent running on start
    const { start, end } = selection;
    inputEl.current.focus();
    inputEl.current.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  }, [selection]);

  const keyHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.code);
    if (e.code === "ArrowUp" /* && inputEl.current.selectionStart === 1 */) {
      setSelection({ start: 0, end: 2 });
      setMilisec((prevState) => prevState + 86400000);
      setDate((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, day: new Date(milisec).getDate() };
      });
    }
    if (e.code === "ArrowDown" /* && inputEl.current.selectionStart === 1 */) {
      setSelection({ start: 0, end: 2 });
      setMilisec((prevState) => prevState - 86400000);
      setDate((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, day: new Date(milisec).getDate() };
      });
    }
  };

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    return e.target.value;
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.main}>
      <h1> Frontend Task</h1>
      <p id="name">Abramov David</p>
      <input
        ref={inputEl}
        value={date_format}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        onKeyDown={keyHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataInput;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для того, что б предотвратить перемещение курсора нужно внутри функции `keyHandler` вызвать `e.preventDefault()`. В таком случае курсор не будет никуда двигаться при нажатии стрелок.
2. Рассинхронизация нажатий и действий происходит из-за разного способа установки стейта внутри `keyHandler`.

Допустим, при первом рендере значения переменных такие:

```
milisec = 1609448400000
date = {
  day: 1,
  month: 0,
  year: 2021,
  hour: 0,
  minute: 0,
  second: 0,
}
```

При нажатии стрелки вверх происходит вызов:

```
setMilisec((prevState) => prevState + 86400000);
setDate((prevState) => {
    return { ...prevState, day: new Date(milisec).getDate() };
});
```

Если подставить значения переменных, то код будет выглядеть так:

```
setMilisec((prevState) => 1609448400000 + 86400000);
setDate((prevState) => {
    return { ...prevState, day: new Date(1609448400000).getDate() };
});
```

Таким образом, происходит рассинхранизация двух значений, потому что milisec устанавливается с учетом прошлого своего значения, а date нет.
Чтобы это исправить, можно устанавливать одинаковое значение внутри двух вызовов функции таким образом:

```
const keyHandler = (e) => {
  if (e.code === "ArrowUp" && inputEl.current.selectionStart < 3) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let nextMilisec = milisec + 86400000;
    setSelection({ start: 0, end: 2 });
    setMilisec(nextMilisec);
    setDate((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, day: new Date(nextMilisec).getDate() };
    });
  }
  if (e.code === "ArrowDown" && inputEl.current.selectionStart < 3) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let nextMilisec = milisec - 86400000;
    setSelection({ start: 0, end: 2 });
    setMilisec(nextMilisec);
    setDate((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, day: new Date(nextMilisec).getDate() };
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Все гениально просто, огромное спасибо !)